# I'm having trouble with Android Studio

Tags: android

Here is the output of the error I received while trying to build the project;

```
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BU�LD FAILED in 59s
28 actionable tasks: 28 executed
```

'top-level build.gradle file;'

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
ext {
compose_version = '1.5.4'
}
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.3'
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0'
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(:app) file;

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id "kotlin-kapt"
id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
android {
compileSdk 34
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.catalin.instagramclone"
minSdk 29
targetSdk 33
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
vectorDrawables {
useSupportLibrary true
}
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
compose true
}
composeOptions {
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.21'
}
packagingOptions {
resources {
excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
}
}
namespace 'com.catalin.instagramclone'
}
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-beta01"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0"
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-beta01"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0'
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

'setting.gradle file;'

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
}
}
rootProject.name = "InstagramClone"
include ':app'
```

gradle-wrapper.properties file;

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Since I have little knowledge of Android and Kotlin, I have not been able to solve the problem for a while after all my research. The content of the project is a clone of the Instagram application and I received the source code from GitHub, but I am getting a build error. Here is the original GitHub link https://github.com/CatalinStefan/InstagramClone